# Can't use $this in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I got one begginer issue. I've got "menu", the menu is styled table and got code in jQuery that makes the menu moves. My question is, why I can't use $this varible in my code? I'm big begginer in jQuery so be patient with me. I will be happy for any answer.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item').hover(function(){
        $($this).stop().animate({paddingLeft: '20px'}, "slow");
}, function(){
        $($this).stop().animate({paddingLeft: '0px'}, "slow");
    });
});
```

My code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfzvq/)

Comment: This was not the question...

Comment: Hum, what's this answer ? I'm just saying that the asker is not asking for something about PHP, but for something about jQuery, and has a doubt about $this !

Comment: He was making a joke because in PHP variables are declared like `$this`. There, not it's been spelled out for you.

Comment: I'm learning both jQuery and PHP, sometimes it's too much for me. :-D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just supposed to be `$(this)`

Answer (score 2):

The `$` prefix (in Javascript/jQuery code) before a variable is typically a convention used to indicate that the variable is a jQuery object (as opposed to a plain Javascript one).  If you've seen it before, it's just like any regular variable.

You should use `$(this)` instead, which 'wraps' `this` in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

often people use `$this` to cache `$(this)` so that they don't have to repeatedly initiate the jQuery object, which is expensive.

```
$this = $(this)
$this.stop()
$this.animate()
// etc...
```

This is done by convention, and the `$` character in javascript has no special meaning. Thought I would mention, as nobody else seems to have mentioned the reason.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item').hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({paddingLeft: '20px'}, "slow");
    }, function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({paddingLeft: '0px'}, "slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this` and `this` are not same. In development  when we write as `var $this = $(this)` than It become's a jQuery object. `$this` denote that in `this` currently we have a jQuery object.It is only for a refrence you can use any other variable for that $this is not necessary.you can write vat `$that = $(this)` and use that It will behave same.